# Using same object instance in Java between methods

Tags: java, oop, hash, oauth, instance

I asked a similar question earlier today and chose an answer, but I don't think I worded it correctly to get the answer I needed. Please consider the code below..

```
public class ClassA {

    private Main main;
    Object obj = new Object;

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
    methodA() {  //called first
        obj.someFunction();
        main.someFunction();
    }
    methodB() {  //called second
        obj.someOtherFunction();
    }
}
```

The object "obj" in my program is an OAuthService instance that must be used throughout the whole process without "re-creating" it (same hash, no changes).

I call to "obj" with methodA, call a function in main, then call "obj" again in methodB. When I print the hashCodes from both methodA and methodB, I get different results, telling me it is "re-creating" the instance.

How can I avoid this?

I'm sure this might sound like a stupid questions to more experienced programmers, but I'm just getting started with programming, and I can't find the solution I need anywhere. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Actual code**

Class "AuthController", where the "obj" is the OAuth10aService "service", methodA is "handlePinButton", and methodB is "handlePinSubmit". I have tried authentication with two other OAuth libraries for java, and got similar errors. Scribe-java is what I'm using now,

```
public class AuthController {

private final String CONSUMER_KEY = "asdbfsdfbsdf";
private final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "asdfsdbvbvfsdsd";


final OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
        .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
        .build(TwitterApi.instance());
final Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

@FXML
public JFXTextField enterPinField;
@FXML
public JFXButton submitPinButton;

private Main main;

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public void handlePinButton() throws Exception { //call first

    System.out.println(service.hashCode());
    String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
    desktop.browse(new URI(authUrl));
    main.secondWindow();

}

public void handlePinSubmit() throws Exception { //call second

    System.out.println(service.hashCode());

    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(enterPinField.getText());
    System.out.println(verifier);

    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
    System.out.println(accessToken);


  }
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
  WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.65 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.51
722985119
Feb 12, 2016 4:47:05 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.65 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.51
960671619
com.github.scribejava.core.model.Verifier@2546ed3b
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$166/1959217067.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Error processing your OAuth request: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter'
    at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:39)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:29)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth10aService.getAccessToken(OAuth10aService.java:86)
    at controller.AuthController.handlePinSubmit(AuthController.java:65)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: can you show the relevant code for the `someFunction` and `someOtherFunction`? it's hard to figure out what the problem is based on your description

Comment: Yeah, I just added it. I have tried two different OAuth libraries, getting a similar error, so I'm guessing the problem is not with Scribe-java, but with the instance of the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Singleton Pattern. Define your class like below and call `MyClass.getInstance()` method instead of `new MyClass()` when you want to get the only one object.

```
public class MyClass
{
    /**
     * Create the only one instance of this class.
     */
    private static final MyClass sInstane = new MyClass();

    /**
     * This is the only one constructor in this class.
     * Because this is 'private', no others can create
     * instances of this class.
     */
    private MyClass()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the only one instance of this class.
     */
    public static MyClass getInstance()
    {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've read about Singleton before, but it wasn't explained this simply.